# Calling the Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I has developed my apps and now I want to integrate them into Facebook. But I realize that it is dificult. I have this init method:

```
<javascript>
    FB.init({
        appId  : '123456789',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml  : true,
        channelUrl : 'http://xyz.dyndns.org:8080/fbchannel.html',
        oauth  : true
    });
</javascript>
```

After that, I can call `FB.login`, and `FB.ui` to prompt to get permission, it's OK. But if I want to get some information with `FB.api()` (for example, get the user name, etc.), it doesn't work. How do I call the API?

The problem is: I can call `fb.init`. `fb.login`, `fb.ui`, and `fb.getLoginStatus`, but I can't call `fb.api`, not even the simplest method.

In my application setting, I used an application in Facebook, and then I typed my URL (a web application), htt://xyz.dyndns.org:8080/... . Is it OK?

(I am a newcomer in making applications in Facebook.)

Comment: `Doesn't work` explains nothing. We could answer with `fix it somehow`, but we will wait for your further explanations otherwise

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting?  Here is a working FB.api call example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="return getInfo();">Get Info</a>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({ appId: '**appId**', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml : true });

  function getInfo() {  
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {
        FB.api('/me',  function(response) {
          alert('User: ' + response.name);
        });
      }
    });
    return false;   
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.I used exactly this code, but it still can't work. I just add 1 line after FB.login(response) { alert("get here"); and this line : get here appears, but FB.api() can't be called. I don't know why, i thinks there are some mistakes when setting my app.

Comment: yeah in the app settings make sure the canvas url matches up with the host where your canvas page is